# how to print a list containing the separate sums of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I'm trying to gain the sum of a list of lists where the output would be [6,2,10] for the defined lists below.

```
data = [[1,2,3], [2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
output =[]
total = 0
for row in data:
  for val in row[0:len(row)]:
   total += val
output.append(total)
print(output)
```

However, the results of this program is [6, 8, 18]. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Each element in list is [*iterable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), this fact makes [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sum) the best option for this task.

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3], [2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> [sum(d) for d in data]
[6, 2, 10]
```

Now, if you want to know what was your problem...

Place the *accumulator* after the *data* loop, and *feed the list* after every *row* loop:

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3], [2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> output = []
>>> for row in data:
...     total = 0
...     for val in row[0:len(row)]:
...         total += val
...     output.append(total)
...
>>> output
[6, 2, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()`:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [2], [1, 2, 3, 4]] 
print(list(map(sum, data)))
# [6, 2, 10]
```

Or list-comprehension:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
print([sum(x) for x in data])
# [6, 2, 10]
```